# Stored Procedure MySql Error in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I don't know what happened to my query. But still error between select case. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

```
/* GENERATE BATCHING NUMBER */
SELECT 
(CASE CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(RIGHT(hcd_batchnumber, 6) AS INTEGER)), 0)+1 AS VARCHAR(11)))
    WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT(CAST('00000' AS VARCHAR(6)), CAST(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(RIGHT(hcd_batchnumber, 6)AS INTEGER)), 0)+1 AS VARCHAR(11)))
    WHEN 2 THEN CONCAT(CAST('0000' AS VARCHAR(6)), CAST(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(RIGHT(hcd_batchnumber, 6)AS INTEGER)), 0)+1 AS VARCHAR(11)))      
    WHEN 3 THEN CONCAT(CAST('000' AS VARCHAR(6)), CAST(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(RIGHT(hcd_batchnumber, 6)AS INTEGER)), 0)+1 AS VARCHAR(11)))
    WHEN 4 THEN CONCAT(CAST('00' AS VARCHAR(6)), CAST(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(RIGHT(hcd_batchnumber, 6)AS INTEGER)), 0)+1 AS VARCHAR(11)))
    WHEN 5 THEN CONCAT(CAST('0' AS VARCHAR(6)), CAST(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(RIGHT(hcd_batchnumber, 6)AS INTEGER)), 0)+1 AS VARCHAR(11)))
    ELSE CAST(COALESCE(MAX(CAST(RIGHT(hcd_batchnumber, 6) AS INTEGER)), 0)+1 AS VARCHAR(11))
END)
INTO batching FROM qrstock_honeycombdt;
```

Comment: Show the error! And the whole Stored Proceedure if it is indeed a SP

Comment: There exists LPAD() function...